# Groovy: Adding name space to an xml tag

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to add name space to xml tags which is developed by using `StreamMarkupBuilder.bind` further details have given below..

My XML Follows,

```
String xml =`<CarXml> 
                 <Cars>
                    <Car>
                      <CarDetails>
                           <Model>Chevrolet Colorado</Model>
                           <Transmission code='A'>Automatic</Transmission>
                           <AirCondType code='R'>Yes</AirCondType>
                           <Passengers>4</Passengers>
                           <Doors>2</Doors>
                           <Luggage>
                               <Large>12</Large>
                           </Luggage>
                       </CarDetails>
                     </Car>
                 </Cars>
              </CarXml>`
 def parsed = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText( xml )

String request = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
       CarRequest(xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")
       {
            CarRateRulesRequestDetails()
            {
                  mkp.yield parsed.Cars.Car.children()

            }
       }
}
```

After doing so i got this

```
<CarRequest xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
      <CarRateRulesRequestDetails>
           <CarDetails>
                <Model>Chevrolet Colorado</Model>
                <Transmission code='A'>Automatic</Transmission>
                <AirCondType code='R'>Yes</AirCondType>
                <Passengers>4</Passengers>
                <Doors>2</Doors>
                <Luggage>
                    <Large>12</Large>
                </Luggage>
           </CarDetails>
      </CarRateRulesRequestDetails>
</CarRequest>
```

**but what i want is**

```
 <CarRequest xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
      <CarRateRulesRequestDetails>
           <CarDetails xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
                <Model xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">Chevrolet Colorado</Model>
                <Transmission code='A'>Automatic</Transmission>
                <AirCondType code='R'>Yes</AirCondType>
                <Passengers>4</Passengers>
                <Doors>2</Doors>
                <Luggage>
                    <Large>12</Large>
                </Luggage>
            </CarDetails>
      </CarRateRulesRequestDetails>
 </CarRequest>
```

How to add namespace in this case..?
Any help is much appriciated..

Comment: There is no difference. Parent namespace is same as the children's. Why is it needed?